# can i create NFC card emulator application using react native,

Tags: android, react-native, nfc, android-tap-and-pay

I have a few NFC cards for different access and I would like to copy the card in my phone. so I can emulate it for my next use and no need to carry the cards with me. like I am doing tap and pay using an Android phone. so here the question is can I create an Android application using react native  framework

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no is the answer.

The Host Card emulation (HCE) part need to be in Java/Kotlin, the part that enables HCE could be in React Native.

Note that HCE cannot emulate all types of NFC Tags, just Type 4A Tags, I believe there is a react native library to wrap around the HCE part to emulate and even smaller specific custom implementation to match an associated reader App.